# How to I render a float as a fraction in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'd like to build a helper that shows floats as string-like fractions (edited to remove my previous word "equations" which was inaccurate).

For example

```
12.25
```

Would be

```
12 1/4
```

I suppose I could build it with a nightmare chain of conditional statements, but that seems messy.  It seems like this should exist in ruby, but I'm not finding a helper.

Comment: How you would represent a `12.33` though?

Comment: like this, 12 1/3 -- really the goal is to have more elegant human readable numbers for units of measure.  They can be rounded.

Comment: Saying they can be rounded changes the question entirely. Rounded to/by what? Calling to_r on a string like '.25' => 1/4...so maybe convert it to a string and split by '.' But as was suggested by Basin, '.33'.to_r => 33/1

Comment: There is the [Rational](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Rational.html) class in Ruby. But it works precisely. It seems like you to want to have some rounding and fuzziness in it. But perhaps some starting point.

Comment: Yup, the Rational class is what I needed to get going, thanks!

Comment: Your question is unclear. What does "string-like" mean? Why can't they just be `String`s? And can you give an example of how you would represent a float as an equation? I can't wrap my head around how you would do that. Do you mean some random equation of one variable, where, when solved for that variable, the solution is the float you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is unclear.

For a start, you need to understand that floating point numbers are imprecise; [they have *discrete representable values*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) -- For example, it's impossible to represent `0.1` precisely.

This is the cause of the [commonly-mislabelled "bug"](http://0.30000000000000004.com/) (in all languages, not just ruby) that:

```
0.1 + 0.2 == 0.30000000000000004
```

Secondly, *not all numbers are rational*. There is no way to represent pi (3.14159...) as a fraction, like you describe.

Thirdly, `12 1/4` is not an equation. An equation must have an equals sign. What you seem to be describing is a [mixed number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction_(mathematics)#Mixed_numbers).

And lastly, and you cannot have poorly-defined requirements like "I want to represent 0.33 as 1/3" - i.e. you need to be very explicit about what rounding rules, if any, should be applied. `0.33` is equal to `33/100`, not `1/3`. So for the purposes of this answer, I'm going to omit any such ill-defined rounding.

Here is how you could programatically try to format mixed numbers in ruby

```
x = 12.25
puts "#{x.to_i} #{x.to_s.to_r - x.to_i}"
  # => "12 1/4"
```

Or, you could do:

```
puts x.to_s.to_r.divmod(1).join(' ')
  # => "12 1/4"
```

Note the use of `to_s` -- that's very much intentional. Without it, you could get "surprising" (but technically correct) results, such as:

```
0.1.to_r.divmod(1).join(' ')
  # => "0 3602879701896397/36028797018963968"
```

...This is because, as I said at the start, floating point numbers have limited precision. (The number 1/10 cannot be represented in binary.)

If you need to avoid any such rounding errors (for example if you're dealing with currency), you should use `BigDecimal` instead of `Float`. (Or maybe `Rational`, in some circumstances.)

Comment: This is a great amount of teaching you gave. Big thanks!  I did not know either where to start or the terminology to use.